# How do I apologize for my bad Japanese?

Tags: usage, phrase-requests

I am writing a short letter in Japanese. I will doubtless make many mistakes. What is a nice way to acknowledge this to the recipient?

---

*I apologise for using the forum incorrectly. With the help of these answers and other sources as indicated in the comments, I drafted an apology for bad Japanese as follows:*

> *三年【さんねん】以上【いじょう】前【まえ】に日本語【にほんご】を勉強【べんきょう】する事【こと】が始【はじ】まる。学習【がくしゅう】時間【じかん】は手短【てみじ】かったら、日本語【にほんご】の表現【ひょうげん】は間違【まちが】っているかも知【し】れません。私【わたし】の日本語【にほんご】が変【へん】だったらすみません。*

*"I have been studying Japanese for a little over three years. As this is short time to be learning, my Japanese is not without errors in expression. If my Japanese is strange, I apologise."*

Comment: I think this question would be a better one if you provided your attempt at writing this, as [we don't do translations.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799)

Comment: Sure, I can provide an attempt. I thought there might be some kind of formula.

Comment: It's also generally a good idea to see if Google has an answer for you before asking on SE.  I just cut-and-pasted your question's title directly into Google and immediately came up with many (many) forum hits on Quora and HiNative addressing exactly this..

Comment: 日本語の勉強をはじめてから三年でして、失礼があれば申し訳ありません。
I'd go with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reading your sentences, I can easily understand what you're trying to say.

So I'll keep my corrections to a bare minimum:

> 三年と少し前に日本語を勉強し始めました。学習時間がまだ短いので、日本語の表現が間違っているかもしれません。私の日本語が変だったらすみません。

Answer (score 1):

> 日本語に慣れてなくてすみません。

This is interpreted as `Sorry I'm not good at Japanese`.

`日本語に` is `Japanese`
`慣れてなくて` means `Not used to`
`すみません` is a formal apology.

Comment: Is there no conflict between using formal すみません while dropping the い in 慣れていなくて (especially in writing)?

Comment: I think it won't be a trouble in most cases, especially in a situation where you need to tell the recipient that you acknowledge that you are aware of the mistakes.
い dropping is seen in official statement that LDP has published.  
https://www.jimin.jp/news/press/chairman_prc/132488.html

Comment: @Kaskade In general, no issue having those combined. For a formal letter it would be better to not drop いs if course (but OP didn’t specify formality level or context).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically, "I am a beginner at Japanese, so I am sorry that my mistakes can't be avoided."
日本語の新米です。文法や単語が間違いですので、しかたがありません。すみません。